# Making changes to a git tag and repushing

Tags: git, git-tag

Can I go into a `tag` in `git` and make changes and repush that tag and new changes?

I tried:

```
 git tags
     0.2.0
     0.2.1

 git checkout 0.2.0
```

Then I made some changes and did:

```
 git add .
 git commit -a -m "Cleanup."
 git push --tags
```

But it is saying no changes to push.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should make a branch for that tag, make a commit in it, and push that branch.

```
git checkout -b branch0.2.0 0.2.0
```

A tag represents a commit, and cannot be changed or moved.

But nothing prevents you to make and publish (push) a branch dedicated to evolutions specific to that tag.

---

"no changes to push." means [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309), which is exactly what happen when you checkout a tag: you are no longer in a branch (with a HEAD for that branch).